# ffmpeg fails with: pipe:1: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record my desktop using pipe, but ffmpeg fails.

OS windows:

`ffmpeg -filter_complex ddagrab=output_idx=0:framerate=5,hwdownload,format=bgra -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -y pipe:1 | cat > test.mp4`

OS mac:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 5 -capture_cursor 1 ⁣ ⁣pipe:1 | cat > output.mkv`

However, on windows, this command works

`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f mpegts pipe:1 | cat > out.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to solve the problem by adding a parameter `-f mpegts`